# rJava install error "JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry"

Tags: java, r, error-handling, rjava

I am trying to load the rJava using the command:

```
 library(rJava)
```

But I get the following error:

```
 Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
   call: fun(libname, pkgname)
   error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

I tried reinstalling both the Java and the R program with the latest versions
but still get these errors..
May I know how I can resolve this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This error is often resolved by installing a Java version (i.e. 64-bit Java or 32-bit Java) that fits to the type of R version that you are using (i.e. 64-bit R or 32-bit R). This problem can easily effect Windows 7 users, since they might have installed a version of Java that is different than the version of R they are using.

http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/

Answer (score 25):

Install 64 bit Java from https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp.
Then in windows cmd run
`setx PATH "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin\server;%PATH%"`
(make sure your path is correct).

Then in RStudio run
`Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="")`

Now, you should be able to run rJava!!

Answer (score 15):

I got the same error resolved by installing same version of R and Java i.e. 64 bits and manually updating the path i.e. ,

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121') # for 64-bit version
```

Comment: This got me passed this error, but now I got another one: "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object"

Answer (score 6):

Under Windows 10, first check your (running) R-Version:

```
R.version
```

If you see something like `x86_64`, a 64-bit version of Java is needed.

Simply downloading and installing the matching Java version (https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) solved the problem for me. No reinstall of R needed (as suggested by other users here). There also was no need to set the `path` explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

R for Windows installer installs by default both 32-bit and 64-bit files. Reinstalling R and unticking 32-bit part solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the r-statistics link cited above, you have to manually download the 64-bit version of Java.  If not, then the 32-bit version will be installed.

So, if you have a 64-bit operating system, then ensure that both R and Java are using the 64-bit installs.  Otherwise, this problem will persist.

Answer (score 3):

This has been killing me and I have tried multiple methods above, it doesn't work. After, I mix all solution to try and below process works for me.

1. Install Java for 64 bit
2. Run below code in windows command
   `setx PATH "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\server;%PATH%"`
   (please change the address acorrding to your dvm.dll real address)
3. Run below in R studio
   `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="")`
   Then I finally can run
   `library(rJava)`
   `library(xlsx)`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and was feeling very down as I couldnt get my analysis done. 
This worked for me :

1. check your operating system. 64 bit or 32 bit. 
   https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/determine-whether-computer-running-32.html
2. uninstall previous versions of Java.
3. delete rJAVA library from Doc>R>win-library. If you have more than 1 versions of R, make sure you delete rJAVA package from all of them.
4. install Java based on system requirement (64 bit or 32 bit).
5. and finally restart R before and after installing rJava package.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `INSTALL_opts=c("--no-multiarch")` to your `install_github()` call:
`devtools::install_github("mne-tools/mne-r", INSTALL_opts=c("--no-multiarch"))`

For more info: https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-r/issues/5#issuecomment-489588267

Answer (score 0):

If R is 64-bit version make sure to install Java 64-bit version!

If R is x86-bit version make sure to install Java x86-bit version!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new directory in C: drive as "library"
2. set your libPath this directory. you need to type

   .libPath("C:/library")
3. reinstall packages which requires java (xlsx, rJava, RJDemetra)
4. it will give error message again but it will work.