# R: Error message installing a package, how to get around it?

Tags: r

I am having an error installing XLConnect for R, this is the error message I get:

```
> install.packages("XLConnect")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/a_garcia_de_paredes/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/XLConnect_0.2-13.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 9633752 bytes (9.2 MB)
downloaded 9.2 MB

package ‘XLConnect’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\a_garcia_de_paredes\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKA18my\downloaded_packages
> library("XLConnect")
Loading required package: XLConnectJars
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnectJars’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: package ‘XLConnectJars’ could not be loaded
```

Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522088/rjava-install-error-java-home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry)

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick.